# The deepin theme is not recognized by Cinnamon because the "gtk-3.20" folder is missing

Tags: 20.04, themes, cinnamon, gtk3

I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit with "cinnamon-desktop-environment" installed.
The link to the theme is the following:
https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-gtk-theme/issues/20
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there a different way of solving the problem than waiting for the fix? That is how to make sure that the theme is recognized by Cinnamon?

Comment: It seems that you have already asked the developers to look into this. What is your question, then?

Comment: Is there a different way of solving the problem than waiting for the fix? That is how to make sure that the theme is recognized by Cinnamon?